# Why doesn't ko.observableArray.length return length of underlying array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Using Knockout, when working with an `observableArray`, you must grab the underlying array (`myArray()`) in order to read the length. I don't understand why `myArray.length` wouldn't return the underlying array's length (instead it returns 0). Is this a bug or is there reason which I've simply missed?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jsm11482/LJVWE/

**JS/Model**

```
var data = {
    name: ko.observable("Test"),
    items: ko.observableArray([
        { name: ko.observable("First Thing"), value: ko.observable(1) },
        { name: ko.observable("Second Thing"), value: ko.observable(2) },
        { name: ko.observable("Third Thing"), value: ko.observable(3) }
    ])
};

ko.applyBindings(data, document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
        <li data-bind="text: value() + ': ' + name()"></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        <strong>data.items.length == </strong>

        <!-- Expecting 3, get 0. -->
        <span data-bind="text: items.length"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>data.items().length == </strong>

        <!-- Expecting 3, get 3. -->
        <span data-bind="text: items().length"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the plain `items` observable is in fact a Function, which has its own `length` property to indicate the number of arguments expected.

From [MDN's page on Functions (properties section)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Properties):

> [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)
>   Specifies the number of arguments expected by the function.

As a developer using the KnockoutJS library I'd also initially *expect* the length of an observableArray to be the length of the underlying array, but I do appreciate the KO library not overriding this Function property though, as that would probably cause other unwanted side-effects.

Comment: Makes sense - I know it's a function but didn't realize that the `length` property indicated the number of arguments for the function - good to know! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is because ko.observableArray is not really an array. It is a function that returns the underlying array.

In your example, since items is a function, you get a `.length = 0`.

Please check this fiddle where I have added spans with some additional properties

http://jsfiddle.net/LJVWE/3/

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to accept Jeroen's answer as it's a bit more complete. I appreciate your help, though!